# Magento Catalog Rules MySQL Integrity Constraint Violation Errors

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm getting this error after long time waiting for Catalog Rules to apply:

> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '44657-0-2' for key 'PRIMARY', query was: INSERT INTO
>   `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` SELECT
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`entity_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`customer_group_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`website_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tax_class_id`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`orig_price` AS `price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`price` AS `final_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`min_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`max_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`tier_price`,
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`.`group_price` FROM
>   `catalog_product_index_price_final_tmp`'

I tried to reindex, restart MySQL and is still the same, after wait like 40 minutes for one rule to be applied I get an error like that.

I also tried locally with the same database and code to apply the rules and they worked well.

I'm running a Magento 1.14 and this is happening after upgrade from a Magento 1.11 but is just happening in one server, not in a test server nor locally with same database and code.

Any suggestion on what I can do to get rules applied?
Any configuration that I need to check on server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `INSERT IGNORE ..`

Comment: How are you running your indexers? One of the fundamental changes between those Magento versions is how the indexers are handled, and in 1.14 they should run on schedule by the Magento cron. This is an indexing issue and I think you'll find that if you let Magento take care of its own indexers on a schedule that you won't continue to have this issue.

Comment: They're on update on save right now, not running on schedule. However if I reindex and try to apply rules doesn't work. But maybe something is changing rows while I'm applying rules. I have to try changing it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Robbie, you were right! Seems that reindex proecess was running several times during the apply rules process and that was causing the issue and the long time to apply. Now it's done in just few mins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On admin:

```
System > Configuration > Index Management > Index Options
```

Change all indexes to *Update when scheduled*, reindex all, apply catalog rules.

That solved my problem.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi , What could be the exact reason for this issue ? Setting indexes to update when scheduled require to reindex every time we make changes in product data.